# How can I obtain the URL of a file that is currently being downloaded by Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

How can I obtain the URL of a file that is currently being downloaded by Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate?

For example, I have this file as is currently being downloaded:

[image]

How can I get the URL where this file is downloaded from?

Right clicking or clicking on the arrow opens this menu, which doesn't give the option to get the URL:

[image]

Comment: @JakeGould Good point but it didn't help :/ I added the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to the Downloads tab should give you the URL.  On a Windows machine, that's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on a Mac.

Random pic of tab:

[image]

This is a little out dated, but you should get the idea of how to find it through the menus:

> http://www.googlechrometutorial.com/google-chrome-general-settings/Google-Chrome-Downloads.html

Comment: Huh. I was just about to post an identical answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this in 2024, it requires going into the "Full Download History" and right clicking the shortened URL here and getting the Link Address:

[image: copy link address image]
(Image from macOS Chromium 122.0.6261.94.)